# Yesod route containing a `Maybe a` argument

Tags: haskell, routes, yesod, option-type

I've been trying to use a `Maybe a` in a route. So far I tried

```hs
/u/#Maybe UserId
/u/#(Maybe UserId)
/u/#Maybe-UserId
```

and

```hs
/u/#MaybeUserId
```

where

```hs
type MaybeUserId = Maybe UserId
```

But without much success.

Strangely enough, `#Maybe-UserId` compiles fine with an handler using `Maybe UserId` but, it's not able to find a match even with the new `PathPiece` instance below.

```hs
instance (PathPiece a) => PathPiece (Maybe a) where
    fromPathPiece s = case s of
        "Nothing" -> Nothing
        _ -> Just $ fromPathPiece s
    toPathPiece m = case m of
        Just s -> toPathPiece s
        _ -> "Nothing"
```

<del>What am I missing to create `Maybe` routes and not having to declare an a type and instance for each and every `Maybe a` that I want to use?</del>

<del>**edit:** The instance works fine when using anything other than `Ǹothing` for some reason.</del>

**edit2:** `"Nothing" -> Nothing` actualy indicates that the `PathPiece` failed parsing, which is not the desired outcome. `"Nothing" -> Just Nothing` does the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

A route with an empty parameter (ending with a slash) reverts to a route ending with the previous path piece, so "/u/" will never match "/u/#MaybeUserId"

So there are two different routes in your optional *UserId* proposition:

```
/u  UserNoIdR  GET

/u/#UserId  UserWithIdR GET
```

*Update*:

You may serve them both from a common handler, if you want:

```
getUserNoIdR = getUserMaybe Nothing

getUserWithIdR userId = getUserMaybe (Just userId)
```

Comment: It requires more code to do and eventually, to maintain. Check the question I found my mistake.

Comment: A route with an empty parameter (ending with a slash) reverts to a route ending with the previous path piece. So there are two different routes here.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone coming from Google, the following is indeed the correct route syntax:

```
/user/#Maybe-UserId    UserR GET
```

for the handler:

```
getUserR :: Maybe UserId -> Handler Html
```

Which you can access with the URLs

```
/user/Nothing  -> Nothing
/user/Just%207 -> Just 7
```